# java force literal when using escape character in jmeter

Tags: java, javascript, jmeter, escaping

Running Jmeter on XP, I have the following scenario:

```
Declare the variable "ServerName" with the value 'serverNameValue'
Declare the a variable "TestResultsFolder" with the value 'c:\results\${ServerName}'
... do samplers ...
Have a simple data writer save result to "${TestResultsFolder}\file"
```

Unfortunately, The data writer is saving to 
'**c:\results\${ServerName}**' instead of '**c:\results\serverNameValue**'

if I put a valid alpha character before the variable, it works:
 '*c:\results_${ServerName}*' yields '*c:\results_serverNameValue*'

Thus, it seems that the \ is escaping the variable declaration of $, causing the program NOT to supply the correct value.

Any thoughts on how I might actually obtain ***c:\results\serverNameValue***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the '\' character have to be escaped, in order to explicit that you need a real '\', and not an escape of the next character?

I would try this : "**c:\\results\\${ServerName}**"

Comment: Yes, escaping the '\' worked - Thanks!

The final solution was to have to slashes:
 *C:\temp\\${ServerName}*

Comment: You can also use forward slashes in paths, even on windows. Using `c:/results/${servername}` shoukd work regardless of string escaping.

Comment: Using forward slashes also worked beautifully, thank you.

Also, my first comment should read "two slashes". Bah.